# Having multiselect in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am pretty new to the AngularJS and Javascript. I currently have a dropdown that looks like:

```
        <div hidden id="mMethod">
            <label style="font-size: medium">Method</label>
            <select name="mMethod" class="form-control" ng-model="request.mMethod">
                <option ng-repeat="mMethod in mMethods">{{ mMethod.value }}</option>
            </select>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="reuqestForm.mMethod.$error"
                 ng-if="reuqestForm.mMethod.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I do want to change this as the multiselect dropdown gets that selected values in the Controller. Currently I have `$scope.request.mMethod` Do I have to change anything in the Controller if I am changing the drop down to be multiselect?

Comment: Hello, is this the functionality you are trying to achieve ? : https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select

Comment: `mMethod` will be an `array` now. So there is possibility that you may have to deal with it

Comment: @GeorgeBailey is there any other directive that can take care of  the multiselect?

Comment: @AndrewAdam Looks like that is not a free one

Comment: if you want to use multi select obviously you're gonna have more than one options now and you are switching to multiselect, so you will want to save multiple options selected. what's the problem ?

Comment: @trx it is under MIT license (you can see it at the top-right corner of the table) so you can quite freely use it :)